# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. 20.0

Tags: server, apache2, letsencrypt

When I try to start my Apache server, I get this message:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited
with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and
"journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Calling `journalctl -xe` returns:

```
Oct 02 10:01:00 mysite.com systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Subject: A start job for unit user@1000.service has finished successfully
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit user@1000.service has finished successfully.

The job identifier is 6994.

Oct 02 10:01:00 mysite.com systemd[1]: Started Session 66 of user admin.
Subject: A start job for unit session-66.scope has finished successfully
Defined-By: systemd 
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit session-66.scope has finished successfully.
The job identifier is 7083.

Oct 02 10:01:48 mysite.com sudo[11130]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
Oct 02 10:01:48 mysite.com sudo[11130]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin(uid=0)
Oct 02 10:03:01 mysite.com sudo[11135]:  admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com
Oct 02 10:03:01 mysite.com sudo[11135]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin(uid=0)
Oct 02 10:03:06 mysite.com sudo[11138]:  admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf
Oct 02 10:03:06 mysite.com sudo[11138]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin(uid=0)
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com sudo[11145]:  admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start apache2
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com sudo[11145]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin(uid=0)
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has begun execution  Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit apache2.service has begun execution. The job identifier is 7173.

Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com apachectl[11156]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/html/www/html] does not exist
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com apachectl[11156]: (98) Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com apachectl[11156]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
0.0.0.0:80
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com apachectl[11156]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com apachectl[11156]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com apachectl[11148]: Action 'start' failed. Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com apachectl[11148]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Subject: Unit process exited 
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.

The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.

Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed  Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 7173 and the job result is failed.

Oct 02 10:03:50 mysite.com sudo[11145]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: It is exactly what it says: for every <VirtualHost> you need a </VirtualHost>

Comment: Yeah i got that part but now it gives a diffrent error now it says:

AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/html/www/html] does not exist
AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: the same for Rewriterule etc

Comment: Unless you’ve been doing things to the default file structure, `/html/www/html` is not a valid location for Apache. You might want `/var/www/html` or some other location in `/var/www`. Given the number of challenges you’re facing with this virtual host config, perhaps you could [edit] your question to include the entire content of the `.conf` file 

Comment: There is no such Ubuntu version as 20.0

Comment: I edited the post with more information because the apache server wont start

Comment: While there may be a bit more information, the details requested yesterday have not yet been added. It would be really helpful to see the contents of your VirtualHost file, as it *looks* like you may be referring to an incorrect directory but, without seeing the configuration file, this is just a guess ...